# Is the SQL IN operator available in Oracle NoSQL Database?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I recently tested some SQL queries in Oracle NoSQL Database in our test cluster. I couldn't find a SQL feature called the IN operator. It will simplify  our queries a lot.
For example,

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE a IN (7, 6, 8)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE a = 7 OR a = 6 OR a = 8
```

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is present in the NoSQL database

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/20.1/sqlreferencefornosql/operator.html

This is a link to the document for IN operator.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I am a high school student....m new to stack community will remember that from next time